# How can I move my cursor horizontally by whitespace in VS-Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

VSCode Version: 1.56.2

Given a line like the following in `plaintext` mode:

```
foo-bar-baz FooBarBaz FOO BAR BAZ
```

With my cursor at the beginning of the line, using `cursorWordPartRight` (bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>right</kbd> on my machine), my cursor will stop in each of these locations:

```
foo-bar-baz FooBarBaz FOO BAR BAZ
   ^^  ^^  ^^  ^  ^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^
```

With my cursor at the beginning of the line, using `cursorWordEndRight` (bound to <kbd>option/alt</kbd>-<kbd>right</kbd> on my machine), my cursor will stop in each of these locations:

```
foo-bar-baz FooBarBaz FOO BAR BAZ
   ^   ^   ^         ^   ^   ^   ^
```

What I'd like to do is to move by whitespace. So with my cursor at the beginning of the line, what function can I use to move by whitespace, stopping in each of these locations:

```
foo-bar-baz FooBarBaz FOO BAR BAZ
           ^         ^   ^   ^   ^
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?  I just want to backward delete a word without regarding to the usual word delimiters

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove the `-` from your `Editor: Word Separators` setting than `cursorWordEndRight`, `cursorWordEndLeft`, `cursorWordRight`, `cursorWordLeft`, etc. act as you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I want all three capabilities.

Comment: Then there are a number of "jumping" extensions that will do this.  For example: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.jump-and-select